# Do I need to explicity state read/write validation rules for each firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Do I need to explicity state read/write (or the more granular alternatives get/list/create/update/delete) validation rules for each collection?

Or is there a validation rule set by default if no rules are provided, or some are not stated?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function userIsAuthenticated() {
      // ...
    }

    allow read: if true;

    allow create: if
      userIsAuthenticated() &&
      request.resource.data.example is string;

    allow update: if
      userIsAuthenticated() &&
      request.resource.data.example is string;

  }
}
```

Above doesn't include `delete` - what happens in this scenario?

Does `delete` default to false, or will it allow data to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't write any rules, all access will be rejected.  You have to write rules to allow access under the conditions you specify.